# How to do paging in Survey Monkey

Tags: curl, surveymonkey

I need to page the results I get back from Survey Monkey. I tried from the docs the following:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Authorization:bearer my.access.token.which.i.have" -H "Content-Type": "application/json" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys?page=2&per_page=5
```

the response seems to ignore the values I am sending in the url `(page=2&per_page=8)`
The response still has as `per_page:50` as the header of the response, and the `links` have, for example for `prev` the value: `https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys?page=1&per_page=50`
What am I missing in the URL structure to get paging correctly?

I will point that I do get a result with my surveys back, which (probably) means I am setup properly to work with the API as far as credentials, correct url and scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes around your url otherwise, your shell will interpret the first `&` and will make the command on the left of `&` run in background (thus ignoring all the parameters you have added on the right of it eg `per_page=5`) :

```bash
curl -i -H "Authorization:bearer my.access.token.which.i.have" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys?page=2&per_page=5"
```

Also `-H "Content-Type": "application/json"` header is not correctly formatted